# Can I specify a target in XCode's storyboard editor?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, target

I have a project, that has multiple targets, each has different resource images, but they use a common storyboard. 
Can I somehow configure the storyboard editor to only work with my specified target?
The problems are:

- A seemingly random target is selected, and it's images are shown in the editor
- Xcode is rebuilding all targets for the storyboard whenever i edit somethings, and this is very time consuming
- If a target fails to build, the storyboard seems to be broken, even if it's a target i'm not working with at the moment -- (broken like only empty image views are shown, custom views are not rendering)

Can this be somehow resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply select the target for each storyboard. Select `show file inspector` and under `Target membership`. Choose your target. As in image there is only one target, if you have multiple target it will show all.

[image]

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I have one storyboard, and many targets, with different image assets. The problem is specifying, with which xcode's editor should work at a given moment.

Comment: You want to choose target at runtime?

Comment: Not in program runtime, but in design time.

Comment: @Battlechicken also experiencing this! not a huge drama since at runtime it works. but makes for previewing the storyboard hard work since it references wrong target assets!